# How to display special character in exe using unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating exe in unity 3d and in that i am writing sentence in vietnamese language when i am converting it from english at that time it display proper but when i create exe ant that time special character are not displaying properly.Image 1 for Actual content Image 2 for Content display in exe

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: So your code works in the editor but not in the .exe? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: where exactly is that text displayed? Is it the log on the console?

Comment: see if this helps - https://answers.unity.com/questions/546213/handling-special-characters-aeouuouo-in-unity.html. hes not having the exact same problem, but similar and found a work around. also, Unity creates a variable, `Application.systemLanguage` its read only, but can be referenced to see if that is your problem. what is your system language set to?

Comment: the problem with this is that the system language wont be the same for all targets across all installs...  which is why im assuming the text is defaulting to standard english, probably your system language.